# Multiplying a variable by 10 not working?

Tags: python

So I'm trying to make it so that when two if statements are true that I multiply a variable by 10 and store it in the same variable. This is all inside of a define statement. What am I doing wrong?
When my code gets run,

```
if goal.isdigit():
    if int(goal) < 5:
        goal = goal*10
        print(goal)
        play()
```

And it meets the conditions, it outputs the input ten times in a row. So if I input a 1, it outputs `1111111111`.

Comment: Looks like `goal` is a string, and `<str> * <num>` gives you `<num>` copies of the string concatenated together.

Comment: is `goal` a string or a number?

Comment: What you may want to do is convert goal to an int before performing the multiplication? Really the trouble though looks to be coming from goal not being an int in the first place.

Comment: @Jeremy Fisher Oh, I see, I forgot to change goal into a number after the original if statement checking if it's a number. *facepalm* Thanks!

Comment: Can you make this a full working program? Most of the parts that could be buggy are missing.

Comment: @tdelaney I already found the issue. But thanks for trying to help!

Comment: In the future, consider posting working examples. In this case, had we known you passed the string "1" instead of the integer 1, it would have been easier to solve.

Comment: @tdelaney Ok, thanks! I'm a little new to StackOverflow, so I'm still getting used to things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that `goal` is a `str`.  When you multiply a string by an integer, it merely replicates the string.  So, `'hello'*2` is `'hellohello'`.  What you want is the number **represented** by the string multiplied by 10.  So,

```
value = int(goal)
if value < 5:
    value *= 10
    print(value)
    play()
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to ensure your goal is an integer.

Consider doing this:

```
if goal.isdigit():
    goal = int(goal)
    if goal < 5:
        goal = goal*10
        print(goal)
        play()
```